# Show posts in category x and y from the 6th most recent post onwards

Tags: posts

I'm struggling with the query for this in WordPress to display posts in a category from the 6th most recent onwards.

Basically, I have a top 5 posts section at the top of a category for featured posts (marked as posts in that specific category AND in a Featured category), then in the page content I don't want any of those top 5 featured posts shown in the regular posts loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__and' => array( 2, 6 ), 'offset' => 5 ) );
```

Comment: And your code looks like..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code, here's a rundown that should work for you.

1. At the top of your template file, start an array, `$featured_posts = array();`
2. In your featured posts loop, in each iteration, add the ID of the post to the array, `$featured_posts[] = get_the_ID();`
3. In your second loop, check to see if the post was already displayed, and if so, skip to the next iteration of the loop: `if ( in_array( get_the_ID(), $featured_posts ) ) continue;`